# Invalid Date : Converting UTC to local

Tags: javascript, c#, date, razor, momentjs

I am using **Moment.js** to convert UTC time to Local in my Razor View Page.The DateTime Format is **2015-12-30 10:13:11.527** and here is my Syntax ..

```
<td><script>document.write(moment.utc('@data.StatusDateTime').local())</script></td>
```

But i am getting Invalid Date as Converted Value..How to Correct it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `StatusDateTime` is a DateTime field you probably want to format it as such before passing to the [`moment.utc`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) method:

```
moment.utc('@user.StatusDateTime.ToUniversalTime().ToString("o")').local()
```

Also notice that I have converted here the `StatusDateTime` to UTC to ensure that we have proper value but if the field is already a UTC date, you don't need to call the `ToUniversalTime` method on it.

Comment: What Does this `o` refer here ..Is it for Local DateTime ?

Comment: No, it's for round-trip format. Checkout the doc: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: DateTime is already a UTC , I need to convert it to Local where a User is viewing ...What should be the real synatx for that ?

Comment: Sure, that's what the `.local()` function of moment js does. But this should be done on the client, not on the server. Your problem was that you were incorrectly calling the `moment.utc` method by passing it an invalid date format. Once you fix this format as shown in my answer all you need is call `.local()` but this will happen on the client, not on the server of course.

Comment: Got it and now the Date is coming in Local but it is coming as `Tue Dec 22 2015 17:41:38 GMT+0530` while i need it like `2015-Dec-22 12:11:38`. How to do it ?

Comment: Please read the documentation of the third party framework you are using (in your case MomentJS). The [`format`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) method is probably what you are looking for. I am that much familiar with MomentJS but just glimpsing at the documentation already could provide some good hints for you. So I guess you need to build the format: `.local().format('YYYY-MMM-DD HH:mm:ss')`.